# Keras - Image Input to LSTM with time_steps

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have a problem which requires that I use LSTM many-to-one architecture i.e. it will take in 19 image frames first and then give out an output.

The image frame has size (128,128,3).

I have been trying since days but could not find the answer, what should be the input_shape for LSTM?

I believe since the image frame is of size 128*128*3, thus the number of units in the input layer would be 49152. Currently the code looks like this:

```
timesteps = 19
data_dim = 128*128*3
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(data_dim,input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(Dense(10))

optimizer = 'sgd'
momentum=0.6
decay=0.0005
nesterov=True
optimizer = SGD(lr=lr, momentum=momentum, decay=decay, nesterov=nesterov)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

This code gives Memory Error after compilation.

Thus is it due to some error in input_shape and other parameters to LSTM or is it due to my computer's hardware?

Comment: Could you share your data processing code? how did you process your train data for model.fit(traindata...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly your achitecture. Try less LSTM units, `data_dim` is way too much.

Considering that your input is also `data_dim`, this will result in more than 4*49152*49152 = 9.663.676.416 weights (not counting biases).

```
model.add(LSTM(less_units, input_shape=(timesteps,data_dim)))
```

---

A sequence of images:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(output_filters,kernel_size,...), input_shape=(timesteps,x,y,channels))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim,...))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!

If I add a layer of CNN before this, how would that look? 
I could not find any good reference for adding CNN layer before LSTM layer for m-to-1 architecture. 
If you could help with that, I would be indebted!

Comment: In addition, is there any idea by which I can reduce the number of units in LSTM? I have already converted the images to grayscale and converted the images to a size of (64,64)

Comment: `model.add(LSTM(less_units, input_shape=(timesteps,data_dim)))`

Comment: No, there is no relation between them.

Comment: The number of units in the input layer of a Neural Network is equal to the number of features in the input. Isn't it?

Comment: The input layer is not the LSTM layer. It's hidden or simply doesn't exist.

Comment: It's `model.add(LSTM(output_dim, input_shape=(timesteps, input_dim)))`

Comment: Okay so, output_dim is the dimension I wish to output from the LSTM layer. Is it?
In addition, what I meant there was the first hidden layer and not the input layer.

Comment: Yes, it is. --- In keras Sequential you don't need to care about input layers.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will try this and would like to bug you for more such questions. :P

Comment: Hey Daniel,
Thanks for the help! It worked.
If I have to input a sequence of images (20 time steps) to LSTM but first pass them through some convolutional layers, then do I need to  change the architecture / arguments of LSTM layer in anyway?

Comment: One possibility was added in the answer. You can also try some ConvLSTM2D layers https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d